# Publishing from AWS lambda to Kinesis Process exited

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-kinesis

I am trying to publish events from aws lambda but I get the following error:

```
Process exited before completing request
```

Here's my code

```
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
  kinesis.PutRecord({
    "Data": event,
    "PartitionKey" : "1",
    "StreamName": "TestStream"
  });
  context.done();
  callback(null, "");
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have `context.done` called before the `callback` function where both are exit callbacks for the handler code. Remove `context.done` in your code, and also do the following change.

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const kinesis = new AWS.Kinesis({apiVersion: '2013-12-02'});

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
  kinesis.putRecord({
   "Data": event,
   "PartitionKey" : "1",
   "StreamName": "TestStream"
   }, 
   function(err, data) {
    if (err)
      console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
    else  
      callback(null, data);        // successful response
   });
}
```

Comment: even without context.done I still get the same error

Comment: the issue is kinesis is not defined in lambda

Comment: note that adding var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
with var kinesis = new AWS.Kinesis({apiVersion: '2013-12-02'}); fixed it

Comment: Updated the answer. Thanks!